# using srec_cat to fill an S-Record file with a word

Tags: binary, embedded, microcontroller, crc32

I have an input file in S-Record format whose unused area needs to be filled with a given word pattern [lets say 0xAABBCCDD] using srec_cat.exe.

I am trying the following syntax

```
srec_cat.exe <original file> -fill <fill pattern word> -within  <startaddress> <end address>  -o <outputfile> −Output_Word
```

This syntax is giving error. Can you help with the correct syntax.

Comment: How about telling us what the error message is!?

Comment: Did you intend to fill the entire file, or just fill the holes?

Comment: Your `<startaddress> <end address>` fields were interpreted as markup and hidden before I edited it - but they should not be there in any case if you are using a `-within` range.

Comment: What does within means ? The entire file ?

Comment: There are examples at http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man1/srec_examples.html#FILLING%20THE%20BLANKS

Comment: The `-within` parameter was in your original question - you tell me what it means!?  From the documentation I am not entirely clear, but I assumed it was what you intended.  I beleive it is a range from the lowest address to the highest address in the existing file.  However it was why I asked whether you were filling holes or filling the entire file (which you chose not to answer) - that is the difference I think between `-over` and `-within`.  It seems odd to fill an existing file (overwriting the existing data) when you could just create a new file filled for a specific range.

Comment: You broke your mark-up again; I fixed it -  again.  Always check the preview panel before committing.  You still have not told us what the error message is.

Answer (score 0):

The `-fill` filter documentation states:

> -Fill *value* *address-range*
>
> This filter may be used to fill any gaps in the data with ***bytes*** equal to *value*. ...

(the highlight on ***bytes*** is mine).

This specifies that the fill value is a byte not a word.

From the [srec_cat examples](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man1/srec_examples.html#FILLING%20THE%20BLANKS) on filling blanks, what you need to use the `-generate` option with `-repeat-data`; something akin to this:

```
srec_cat <infile>
        −generator ’(’ <startaddress> <end address> −minus −within <infile> ’)’ 
                   −repeat-data 0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0xdd 
        −o <outfile>
```

(line-wrapped for clarity)

Note however that you may need to change the byte order to suit the required endianness of the target.  I have omitted the `-Output_Word` option in your original - that may or may not be needed.

I am guessing to some extent; you may need to experiment - the syntax of the srecord utilities and its documentation are somewhat arcane.  Generators are described in the [srec_input documentation](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man1/srec_input.html) which is not itself a utility but describes the generic input common to all srecord utilities.

Comment: @user1771823 : No, you cannot replace 0xff with 0xffffffff; that was the point of my answer!  And as I also pointed out, if you fill one hole with 4 0xff, what is the difference between that and filling it with one 0xffffffff?

Comment: @user1771823 :  If you want to fill with an arbitrary sequence on bytes, use the `-repeat-data` option.  Again see in the srec_cat examples.

Comment: @user1771823 :  You need then to edit your question; it makes no sense to give and answer to a question that has not been asked.

Comment: @user1771823 : But it still says 0xFFFFFFFF which allows a different solution than 0xAABBCCDDEE, and you continue to keep readers in the dark regarding the error message.  You have specified *actual* filenames, but only used *paceholders* for the range, which is a confusing mix - it is either a real command line or a syntax guide - not both.

Comment: This is the command I used                                                                                          **C:\mks\temp\Srecord>srec_cat App_Original.s37 -repeat-data 0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0xdd -
over App_Original.s37 -o output27.s37**                                                                 
This is the error I get **misplaced "-REPeat_Data" option
Usage: srec_cat [ <option>... ] <filename>...
       srec_cat -Help
       srec_cat -VERSion
       srec_cat -LICense**

Comment: I'm just reading the documentation and examples here! They lack clarity but it appears that that -repeat-data is *data_source* to the `generate` option, not a direct option for `srec_cat`.

Comment: I tried again with "generate" That also is throwing some errors **C:\mks\temp\Srecord>srec_cat App_Original.s37 -generator '(' -over App_Original.
s37 -minus -within App_Original.s37 ')' -repeat-data 0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0xdd -o outfile.s37** and here is the output error message I got 
**srec_cat: the --generate range requires two numeric arguments**

Comment: @user1771823 : OK, I though the `-over` did that for you since the documentation says you can use it anywhere a range is valid (apparently not!).  Just use an explicit range as in the examples.  Edited.

Comment: I think I have answered your original question; `-fill` is not the correct filter for multi-byte values.  This now either deserves a new question or your question should have been just *"How do I fill holes with a multi-byte word using `srec_cat`?"* which now seems to be what we are trying to answer despite not being what you asked.

Comment: Tried the explicit range also. Still no luck                **C:\mks\temp\Srecord>srec_cat App_Original.s37 -generator '(' 0x10 0x20000 -minus
 -within App_Original.s37 ')' -repeat-data 0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0xdd -o outfile.s37**            The error I got is                                                                    **srec_cat: the --generate range requires two numeric arguments**