# Filling memory gaps in Linker script with GHS MULTI

Tags: c, assembly, memory-management, linker-scripts, srecord

I have some memory gaps in my .srec file after building my code in GHS MULTI. I have tried =fill and FILL() commands but there was no change. Can anyone suggest a solution. I need a solution that can be used in linker script.

Also can anyone give some complete working examples of =fill and FILL() Section attributes.

I have tried as following,
SECTIONS
{
.text CLEAR : FILL(0xFF) >.
or
.text FILL(0xFF) : >.
or
FILL(0xFF)
.text : > .
or
.text = 0xFF : > .
or
.text : > . =0xFF
or
.text : =0xFF > .
}
I have tried all the mentioned scenarios but there was no memory filled at required loaction
and when using clear some memory is getting framented at end address( First it was S315 in .srec but when used CLEAR it became S309)

Comment: You might like to use the tool "srecord", as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41654744/11294831).

Comment: They are using srec commands right can we add those command in linker script or is there any other procedure

Comment: AFAIK you cannot call arbitrary commands in a linker script. Use a post-link step in your build, be it a shell script, a Makefile or an IDE.